# Move navigation bar to center when tab bar scrolled

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create navigation bar like in contacts application on iPhone, seems like default solution but I can't find any code examples. What I want to do is to move my navigation bar from the left to center and change font size when user scrolls tab bar. Please see screenshots:
[image: Before Tab Bar with contacts scrolled]
[image: After Tab Bar with contacts scrolled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large title and title of navigation bar

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let scrollAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            scrollAppearance.shadowColor = .white
            scrollAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navigationBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
            navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow")
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollAppearance
            navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        } else {
            navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
            navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

this line is responsible for showing this large left title in navigation bar

```
 navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
```

this is the font for largeTitle and small center title

```
 navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
```

how to use it

```
let vc = ViewController()

let embeddedNav = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

present(embeddedNav,animate:true)
```

set the title in view did load method of vc

```
navigationItem.title = "Some title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .black, backgoundColor: .spWhite, tintColor: .white, title: "Your Title", preferredLargeTitle: true)
    }

extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor

        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
}
}
```